# C# - Writing a string next to a line or delete a string

Tags: c#

I want to write a string next to a line, randomly could be any line, also I want to know how to delete a line from it, here is how my `StreamReader` works:

```
using (StreamReader sb = new StreamReader("admin.txt"))
{
  string[] ffoo = File.ReadAllLines("admin.txt");
  string[] ppoof = ffoo[0].Split(';');

  string line;

  while ((line = sb.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    if (line.StartsWith("#" + Server.Name.ToLower() + ": "))
    {
      string[] punch = line.Split(';');
      if (!punch.Contains(Channel.Name.ToLower()))
      {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("admin.txt");
        str.Append(Channel.Name.ToLower() + ";");
        return;
      }
  }
}
```

Here is how the list is made:

```
#main: alien;nobody;somebody;
#devs: headdev;wae;
```

It reads it fine just it can't write something next to main channel, I mean I can only write a line or a string next to end of it which is on dev, and I want to write something on main, also I have some problems on how to delete an admin from main or dev. also this file would be oversize, maybe includes 500 lines at all after we use it, so please if you can give a solution for big files, thanks!

Comment: `StringBuilder` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @SLaks Then what should i do for writing a line and how about deleting a string from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling StringBuilder.Append it appends to the end of the string.

When calling the StringBuilder(string) constructor it will append to the string passed as parameter for the constructor.

In this case you are passing "Admin.txt" as a string, but you really want to pass the content of Admin.txt, so you need to read the content of it.

This should do the trick:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("admin.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
        if (lines[i].StartsWith(string.Format("#{0}: ", Server.Name.ToLower()))
        {
            if (!lines[i].Split(';').Contains(Channel.Name.ToLower()))
                lines[i] += ";" + Channel.Name.ToLower();
        }
    }
File.WriteAllLines("admin.txt", lines);
```

I'm sorry if I misunderstood what you wanted to do though.

Comment: Something is making problems, not sure why but i tried it and whenever client connects to server and runs this client crashes, maybe it generates many of errors in chat